# Percorrer uma table e pegar dados com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sou novato com Javascript e estou precisando percorrer as linhas de uma tabela e caso o `checkbox` esteja marcado, pegar o valor de uma coluna(ID) e armazenar em um `array`.

Comment: Dê um exemplo de como está sua table.

Comment: ID? Você quer pegar o valor de uma outra `TD` na mesma linha que está o `checkbox` é isso?

Comment: O ideal é mostrar como está o código html da página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não informou a estrutura da tabela, mas, não importa a estrutura, o código abaixo irá pegar a `id` da coluna que você indicar na variável:

```
var coluna = 3; // coluna em que está o ID
```

O código percorre cada linha da tabela e verifica se há um `checkbox` marcado; caso haja, ele irá pegar o `id` da `td` (coluna) informada na variável acima (`var coluna`) e inserir na array `var ids = [];`.

**Veja exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   var ids = [];
   var coluna = 2; // coluna em que está o ID
   
   $("table tr").each(function(){
      
      if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")){
         
         ids.push($(this).find("td:eq("+(coluna-1)+")").attr("id"));
      }
      
   });
   console.log(ids);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <th>
      Coluna 1
   </th>
   <th>
      Coluna 2
   </th>
   <th>
      Coluna 3
   </th>
   <tr>
      <td id="linha1">
         <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td id="linha1_1">
         col 2, linha 1
      </td>
      <td id="linha1_2">
         col 3, linha 1
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="linha2">
         <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
      <td id="linha2_1">
         col 2, linha 2
      </td>
      <td id="linha2_2">
         col 3, linha 2
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="linha3">
         <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
      <td id="linha3_1">
         col 2, linha 3
      </td>
      <td id="linha3_2">
         col 3, linha 3
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```